# Caesar encryption program doesn't produce the expected ciphertext

Tags: c, encryption

I'm new to c and I am writing a program that will encrypt a text file with a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). Whenever I run it it just converts the letters to a SOH character.

encryption.c

```
char *lowerAlpha= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxxyz";
char *upperAlpha= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

int encrypt(int c, int amount)
{
    char* alpha;
    int retVal = c;
    int i;

    if(isalpha(c))
    {
        if(islower(c))
        {
            alpha = lowerAlpha;
            i = (c - 'a' - amount) % 26;
            retVal = alpha[i];

        }
        else if(isupper(c))
        {
            alpha = upperAlpha;
            i = (c -'A' - amount) % 13;
            retVal = alpha[i];
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

and in another file where my main method is I use

```
encryptFile(inputfile, outputfile, 13);
```

Comment: You forgot to say "quote-unquote encryption"

Comment: Suggested parenthesis in `while( (c = fgetc(inputF)) != EOF)`

Comment: I was seeing if 13 would work because 26 wouldn't work. Adding the parenthesis to the while loop got rid of the SOH but now it doesn't write anything.

Comment: Try to print ((-3) % 2) (as an integer).

Comment: Where what I put it and what am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You're subtracting `'A'` or `'a'` during encryption to shift character values into the `0 .. 25` range, and you're never adding anything back to turn them back into letters.

Comment: Wouldn't retVal = alpha[i] get the new character based on shifted value moded by 13?

Comment: @user2337029 Technically, yes. However that "character" is likely to be outside the range of printable ASCII characters. Ask yourself this - if I am working with the character 'a' when I see `c - 'a' - amount`, what's the result (`-13` in your specific case, I think). Make sure you understand what C does with the `%` operator when given negative numbers - it might not be what you're expecting. And `-13` when converted to an 8-bit unsigned character is going to be 243 - outside the ASCII range but might show something if your character set is ISO-8859 or something...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, It made me realize that I had the encryption algorithm wrong where it should be    c - 'a' + amount